# Encoded HTML where it shouldn't be

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions

If you [ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and it doesn't validate, some encoded HTML ends up in the sidebar.

[image: screenshot]

That should probably be fixed.

I am using Google Chrome 15 on Mac OS X.

Comment: Maybe it's an easter egg... `:D`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yet another string that fell victim to an ASPX -> Razor conversion. Fixed in the next build, thanks.